# What is the best way to embed swf into html page

Tags: html, flash

I am trying to embed .swf file into html page.
Width and Height of swf is 1024*768.
I specify 'width' and 'height' as 100%.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<object style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <embed src="frontend/flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" >
</object>
</div>
```

It embeds swf with 1350px*150px for some reason, not 100% of the height of the file.

If I specify dimensions in pixels for tag `embed`, it will work.

But I am very curious, why it does not work with %.
Thank, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try swfobject: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject.
It`s very simple to add Flash and Flashvars.

Here with 100%:
http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/

```
swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "flashContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should lookup the tag in the html docs on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed). It specifies that the `embed` tag has attribute `height` that is the displayed height in CSS pixels. Since `100%` is not a valid pixel value it will not recognize that value.